# Create elements in target XML using data from source XML as element name using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My source XML contains both data and "metadata", describing the target XML.
Source data is a generic collection of entries (fields) and my goal is to create an XML with specific tag names.
Is it possible to convert the source below into target using XSLT? 
**Source:**

```
<section>
   <name>TaxpayerInfo</name>
   <field>
       <name>firstName</name>
       <value>John</value>
  </field>
  <field>
       <name>lastName</name>
       <value>Smith</value>
  </field>
 </section>
```

**Target**

```
 <taxpayerInfo>   
   <firstName>John</firstName>    
   <lastName>Smith</lastName> 
 </taxpayerInfo>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following XSLT (1.0).

It assume's the 'section' element in your original document will be the definition of the elements you want.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="name" />

    <xsl:element name="{$fieldName}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="field"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="name" />
    <xsl:element name="{$fieldName}">
      <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using this xslt against your example XML gave me the following result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TaxpayerInfo>
  <firstName>John</firstName>
  <lastName>Smith</lastName>
</TaxpayerInfo>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="taxpayerInfo">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="field[position() = 1]">
        <xsl:element name="firstName">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="field[position() = 2]">
        <xsl:element name="lastName">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="name"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That will do it. BUT I don't know in advance what data the source will carry. <br> I'm receiving the information from  the third party and I have to convert it into target format. In other words, instead of having <br>    <element name="lastName> <br> I need something like <br> <element name= value of field/name> (at least that what I'd code in Java.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the forum, didn't know how to edit the comment properly. Thanks, that will do the transform. I probably wasn't clear enough with the question. I don't know in advance what data the source will carry. I'm receiving the information from  the third party and I have to convert it into target form. In other words, instead of having `<element name="lastName>` I need something like `<element name= value of field/name>` (at least that what I'd code in Java).